# Динамический вызов массивов из xml

Tags: java, android, xml

В xml-файле есть несколько массивов с номерами 0,1,2,3..., при нажатии на элемент `ListView`, считывается id нажатого item и значение передается в `Intent` , в новой `Activity` происходит заполнение нового `ListView`. Вопрос, как указать новому `ListView`, чтобы он загружал массив соответствующий id, полученному от `Intent`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для простого построения списков с константными значениями каждого списка и выбором текущего списка по некоторому номеру предлагаю такое простое решение:

Создаем необходимые списки с номерами в ресурсах (res/values/strings.xml):

```
<resources>

    <string-array name="a0">
        <item>One 1</item>
        <item>One 2</item>
    </string-array>

    <string-array name="a1">
        <item>Two 1</item>
        <item>Two 2</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

Теперь код, который по полученому номеру (здесь переменная *id*) отобразит список с соответствующим индексом:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    int id = 1; // какой список отображать, здесь указываем на a1

    // получаем идентификатор на основе номера
    int idArray = getResources().getIdentifier( "a" + id, "array", getPackageName());

    // получаем значения по иденттификатору
    String[] array = getResources().getStringArray(idArray);

    ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```