# парсинг xml в массив String

Tags: java, android, xml, xmlparser

вот предположим у меня есть xml файл в проекте андроид.

```
<people>
  <name>denis</name>
  <name>ivan</name>
</people>
<people>
  <name>bobic</name>
  <name>sharick</name>
</people>
```

как перевести все данные в стринговый массив?

P.S. я не разобрался сам с тем как использовать SAX. ребят, мне нужен код, а не ссылка на обучающие материалы. там для примеров парсинга приводят сложные структуры xml с кучей разных тегов без объяснений кода. Вроде: "вот пример, все и так понятно" Пожалуйста очень нужно.

Comment: вам может [что то такое](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/635254/177345) нужно, а не статический массив?

Comment: Что делать, когда [кто то ответил](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) на ваш вопрос

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно использовать структуру:

```
<resources>
    <string-array name="people">
        <name>denis</name>
        <name>ivan</name>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

и перевести в массив:

```
String[] array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.people)
```

Comment: tim_taller спасибо, чувак!))) большое спасибо

Comment: @Иван, если ответ Вам помог, то отметьте его как решение вопроса (галочка под количеством голосов).