# Замена содержимого в ArrayAdapter

Tags: java, android

Есть файл `arrays.xml`, в котором объявлены 2 массива строк:

```
<string-array name="firstList">
    <item>Один</item>
    <item>Два</item>
    <item>Три</item>
    <item>Четыре</item>
    <item>Пять</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="secondList">
    <item>One</item>
    <item>Two</item>
    <item>Three</item>
    <item>Four</item>
    <item>Five</item>
</string-array>
```

Также имеется класс `MainList`, унаследованный от `ListFragment`:

```
public class MainList extends ListFragment {

//объявляем адаптер
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    //инициализируем адаптер и устанавливаем содержимое по 
    умолчанию (отображается при запуске активити)
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.firstList));
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Как при клике на пункт списка поменять содержимое адаптера с `R.array.firstList` на `R.array.secondList`?

Comment: Возможно вам больше подойдет [такое решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/635254/177345), в зависимости от требуемой логики. Естественно, динамическим элементом может быть не только число, а и символы и их комбинация

Comment: Да, спасибо, это очень полезная возможность

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//Читаем оба ресурса в разные переменные:

List<String> firstList=Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.firstList));
List<String> secondList=Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.secondList));
//Создаем адаптер с первым списком
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, firstList);
```

В случае необходимости (по клику или как там у вас) чистим список и добавляем в адаптер значения из второго списка

```
adapter.clear();
adapter.addAll(secondList);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

пересоздать адаптер либо заменить значения массива и обновить адаптер

Comment: Пересоздать адаптер - это обнулить ссылку на него, а затем создать адаптер с таким же именем через new? Это имеется ввиду?

Comment: да, обнулять ссылку необязательно