# Подгрузить разные ресурсы в одну активити

Tags: android, ресурсы

Извиняюсь, может в заголовке не совсем корректно выразился, но идея такова:
Есть файл n0.txt в raw
Он подгружается в виде текста с через такую активити:

```
package ru.xxx.yyy;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.webkit.WebView;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class ZOPP extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_zopp);
        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        //получаем строку и формируем имя ресурса
        String resName = "n0";
        Log.i("name", resName);
        Context context = getBaseContext(); //получаем контекст

        //читаем текстовый файл из ресурсов по имени
        String text = readRawTextFile(context, getResources().getIdentifier(resName, "raw", "ru.xxx.yyy"));

        webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, text, "text/html", "en_US", null);
    }

    //читаем текст из raw-ресурсов
    public static String readRawTextFile(Context context, int resId)
    {
        InputStream inputStream = context.getResources().openRawResource(resId);

        InputStreamReader inputReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
        BufferedReader buffReader = new BufferedReader(inputReader);
        String line;
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        try {
            while (( line = buffReader.readLine()) != null) {
                builder.append(line);
                builder.append("\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return null;
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

И выводится на экран через разметку:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Есть необходимость подгружать и выводить на этот же экран и другие ресурсы n1.txt, n2.txt, ... n100.txt
(В отдельном файле лайаут с разметкой будет список с кнопками на "каждую" n.txt)

Мне нужно, чтобы активность подтягивала ресурсы n1.txt, n2.txt, ... n100.txt в зависимости от того, на какую кнопку я нажму. Сейчас у меня есть лайаот вида:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnAct1"
    style="@style/ButtonText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageViewClip"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="false"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:width="200dp"
    android:background="@drawable/style"
    android:text="Закон о защите прав потребителя" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnAct2"
    style="@style/ButtonText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageViewClip"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="false"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:width="200dp"
    android:background="@drawable/style"
    android:text="Комментарии к Закону о защите прав потребителя" />
```

И на каждую кнопку приходится вешать собственную активность, т.к. она «не умеет» различать на какую кнопку я нажал

Можно ли это сделать, не создавая под каждый ресурс отдельную активность?

Comment: не только можно , но и безусловно нужно. При нажатии на кнопку  вы программно формируете resName - `"n" + number`/ При нажатии вперед к number прибавляете один, назад - отнимаете (так же следите за выходом из диапазона) и вызываете чтение нового файла (метод `readRawTextFile()`). Так же есть [вариант с ресурсами](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/635254/177345)

Answer (score 2):

Слушатель умеет отличать какие кнопки нажаты. Для этого на каждую кнопку задаем уникальный id. В вашей активити реализуйте интерфейс View.OnClickListener, в onCreate активити задайте для кнопок "слушателем" вашу активити. Метод onClick вызовется при клике на любой из привязанных к нему кнопок, в параметр v передается та кнопка, по которой кликнули. Сравниваем по id. В зависимости от кнопки меняем в вебвью содержитмое

```
public class ZOPP extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_zopp);
        findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(this)
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        if(v.id == R.id.button1){
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Решение хорошее, но не идеальное: в данном случае нужно будет вручную прописать действие при нажатии на определенную кнопку. В идеале бы автоматически подгружать ресурс в зависимости от нажатой кнопки

Comment: А что не так? Сохраняйте текущий номер ресурса в n, по нажатию на кнопку назад подгружаете n-1, по нажатии на кнопку вперед - n+1

Answer (score 2):

Если на каждый новый файл у вас назначена своя кнопка, то вы можете указать имя этого файла в xml-разметке кнопки, прикрепив его к полю tag, для каждой кнопки - свой:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnAct1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:tag="n1"
    android:text="Закон о защите прав потребителя" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnAct2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:tag="n2"
    android:text="Комментарии к Закону о защите прав потребителя" />
```

Затем повесить общий слушатель на все кнопки через имплементацию интерфейса в активии и при обработке клика читать этот тэг и по нему выводить текст:

```
public class ZOPP extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

final Context context;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_zopp);
        Button btn1 = findViewById(R.id.btnAct1);
        btn1.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button btn2 = findViewById(R.id.btnAct2);
        btn2.setOnClickListener(this);
        context = getContext();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        // получим имя файла, прикрепленного к кликнутой кнопке
        String resName =(String) v.getTag(); 
        String text = readRawTextFile(context,  context.getResources().getIdentifier(resName, "raw", "ru.xxx.yyy"));
        webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, text, "text/html", "en_US", null);
    }
}
```

Comment: @ru38irk добавил еще с передачей контекста в анонимный класс слушателя и получения ресурсов из него

Answer (score 1):

Почему бы Вам не сделать `RecyclerView` со списком такого плана: "Закон 1 ", "Закон 2", "Закон 3" итд, и по нажатию на позицию передавать `PutExtra` уже на WebViewActivity и по позиции открывать просто нужный файл? Получится 2 активити или 2 фрагмента, расширять можно до бесконечности)))

Comment: Логика понятно, но не могу сообразить как это сделать программно?

Comment: @ru38irk почитайте про RecyclerView ?

Comment: @ru38irk делаете к примеру массив JSon, у него два поля название типа name: "Закон1 " и ключ - имя файла например key:  n0. По клику getAdapterPosition делаете putExtra и передаете ключ который используете как resName . Ну и далее у вас уже есть код который педалит ваш resName. В идеале можно вместо ваших файлов тхт сделать базу данных к примеру sqlite и просто читать ее и крутить вертеть как хотеть.